# Forma de listón a través de CSS

Tags: html, css

Quiero hacer este diseño con CSS puro

[image: Card]

Pero no encuentro la manera de hacer el listón *(amarillo)*
Acá esta el código que llevo:

HTML: *(he usado bootstrap para maquetar)*

```
   <div class="container">
     <div class="row">
       <div class="col-lg-4">
         <div class="card3">
           <div class="top-div">
             <!-- Icon -->
           </div>
             <!-- Este es el div del liston -->
           <div class="ribbon"></div>
           <div class="bottom-div">
              <!-- Text -->
           </div>
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
    .card3 {
      width: 250px;
      height: 400px;
      position: relative;
    }

    .top-div {
      width: 100%;
      height: 50%;
      background-color: #FFFFFF;
      border-radius: 12px 12px 0px 0px;
      border: 1px solid #FAC22C;
    }

    .bottom-div {
      width: 100%;
      height: 50%;
      background-color: #FFFFFF;
      border-radius: 0px 0px 12px 12px;
      border: 4px solid #FAC22C;

    }

    .ribbon {
      background-color: #FAC22C;
      width: 100%;
      height: 50px;
      position: absolute;
      top: 40%;
    }
```

- `.card3`: es el contenedor principal.
- `.top-div`: es el contenedor de arriba con borde delgado donde ira el icono.
- `.bottom-div`: es el contenedor de abajo con borde ancho donde ira el texto.
- `.ribbon`: es el listón al que necesito darle forma.

Comment: ¿Tienes algún sitio web donde se utiliza?

Comment: Por favor como te recomendé en la otra pregunta, compartenos lo que llevas aunque este incompleto.

Comment: Ya lo edite, ya fui mas especifico

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Creo que esto es algo muy similar a lo que buscas, lo que he hecho es jugar con el `z-index` de los elementos para que de esa forma que buscas, pero es muy rebuscado. También le he agregado algunas variables al css para que puedas modificar valores como el tamaño, el color y el borde de los bloques. Seria mucho mas fácil si usaras un svg con la forma del listón que buscas.

```css
:root {
    --block-sup-h: 100px;
    --block-bot-h: 100px;
    --block-border-r: 22px;
    --block-bg: white;
    --main-color: #ff5722;
}

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Roboto';
}

.card {
    width: 250px;
    border-radius: var(--block-border-r);
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
    align-items: center;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px #00000040;
    position: relative;
}

.card__block {
    border-radius: var(--block-border-r);
    background: var(--block-bg);
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.card__block--bg {
    height: 100%;
    border-right: 2px solid var(--main-color);
    position: absolute;
}

.card__block--top {
    height: var(--block-sup-h);
    z-index: 130;
}

.card__block--bottom {
    height: var(--block-bot-h);
    text-align: center;
    border-top-right-radius: 0;
    border: 2px solid var(--main-color);
    border-top: none;
    z-index: 150;
}

.card__ribbon {
    color: white;
    font-size: 22px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 60%;
    height: 50px;
    background: var(--main-color);
    position: relative;
    z-index: 150;
}

.card__ribbon-corner {
    height: 70px;
    width: 60px;
    background: var(--main-color);
    border-radius: 50px 0 0 22px;
    position: absolute;
}

.card__ribbon-corner--left {
    top: var(--block-sup-h);
    left: -10px;
    z-index: 10;
}

.card__ribbon-corner--right {
    bottom: var(--block-bot-h);
    right: -10px;
    transform: rotateX(180deg) rotateY(180deg);
    z-index: 120;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="card__block card__block--bg"></div>
  <div class="card__block card__block--top"></div>
  <div class="card__ribbon">research</div>
  <div class="card__ribbon-corner card__ribbon-corner--left"></div>
  <div class="card__ribbon-corner card__ribbon-corner--right"></div>
  <div class="card__block card__block--bottom">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Excelente respuesta, con el resultado esperado +1

Comment: Sorprendente, muchísimas gracias

Answer (score 3):

Lo puedes hacer **(aunque no es un resultado 100% idéntico)** de esta forma:

- Para el contorno inferior que tiene un color, usamos la propiedad `border` y sus variantes; es decir `left`, `bottom` y `right` y además le indicamos una medida en pixeles que le de un efecto de grosor y se disntingan dichas líneas
- Usamos `border-radius` para indicar la curvatura que cada una de las esquinas va a tener (tratando de igualar lo expuesto en la imagen) en el caso del listón
- El cuadro de texto que esta debajo del listón lo podemos ubicar mediante `margin`
- Para tratar de igualarlo a su base inferior, lo movemos con `padding`
- Con `box-shadow` logramos el efecto de sombra

**EJEMPLO**

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <title>JS Bin</title>
      <style>
        :root {
          --color-fuente-fondo: white;
          --fuente-comun: Verdana;
          --efecto-lineas-borde: 2px solid #FDC41F;
        }
        .container {
          background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.5);
          display: flex;
          justify-content: center;
        }
        .caja-regalo {
          background-color: var(--color-fuente-fondo);
          box-shadow: 7px 5px rgba(0,0,0, 0.5);
          border-radius: 10px;
          height: 150px;
          margin: 30px;
          width: 100px;
        }
        .caja-regalo--liston {
          background-color: #FDC41F;
          border-radius: 20px 0px 19px 0px;
          height: 30px;
          margin-top: 50px;
          width: 109px;
        }
        .caja-regalo--texto {
          color: var(--color-fuente-fondo);
          font-family: var(--fuente-comun);
          font-size: 12px;
          font-weight: bold;
          padding-top: 7px;
          text-align: center; 
        }
        .caja-regalo--cajaTexto {
          border-bottom: var(--efecto-lineas-borde);      
          border-left: var(--efecto-lineas-borde);
          border-right: var(--efecto-lineas-borde);
          border-radius: 0px 0px 11px 9px;
          font-family: var(--fuente-comun);
          font-size: 10px;
          height: 62px;
          margin-top: -4px;
          padding-top: 10px;
          text-align: center;
          width: 98px;
        }
      </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <section class="container">
      <div class="caja-regalo">
        <div class="caja-regalo--liston">
          <p class="caja-regalo--texto">RESEARCH</p>
        </div>
        <div class="caja-regalo--cajaTexto">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Y pues esta imagen muestra el resultado final que fue a lo máximo que me pude acercar

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Y no hay alguna forma de hacerle ese efecto estirado al div?

Comment: Sigo buscando @ByronJimenez por que al momento es lo que tengo, pero si logro mejorar el diseño pues te lo comparto